# Array of name with spaces in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Please find my script and the output

```
#!/bin/bash
verify=("Tom Dick Harry" "Ricky" "Deep Rising")

function verifyServices()
{
        param=("${!1}")
        for i in ${param[@]}
        do
                echo $i
        done
}

verifyServices verify[@]
```

Output :-

> Tom
>
> Dick
>
> Harry
>
> Ricky
>
> Deep
>
> Rising

Expected output :-

> Tom Dick Harry
>
> Ricky
>
> Deep Rising

Why? Is my array declaration wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes inside the function:

```
function verifyServices() {
    param=("${!1}")
    for i in "${param[@]}"; do
       echo "$i"
    done
}

verifyServices verify[@]
Tom Dick Harry
Ricky
Deep Rising
```

**Main problem in your code is this line:**

```
for i in ${param[@]}
```

Due to spaces for loop is considering them as separate arguments.

It should be:

```
for i in "${param[@]}"
```

Comment: ohh.. these mistakes hurts

Comment: Yes in shell scripts quoting can make a big difference.